# Where collections are used in java web application development?

Tags: collections

1. I want know where **Collections** (e.g. array lists)are is useful in real time web application development. I already know the properties of an array list, like duplicates allowed,insertion order is preserved etc.
2. Where the `sort` method is useful(e.g. `collections.sort()`). We use sql queries to sort the data in ascending/descending order.
3. How we realized that thread safety is required/not required.

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayList**

The class **java.util.ArrayList** provides resizable-array, which means that items can be added and removed from the list. It implements the **List interface**.

An **ArrayList** is a dynamic data structure so it can be used when there is no upper bound on the number of elements.

A simple **Array** in java is a static data structure, because the initial size of array cannot be changed, so it can be used only when the data has a known number of elements.

2. For your second question you must refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108207/sort-a-list-with-sql-or-as-a-collection)
3. for Thread safety refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code)

Next time before asking such a question try searching yourself. Feedback much appreciated.